# Pass value of label text from html to .ts in ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to ionic , can anyone please tell me that how to pass value of label text from html to .ts file... my code is

```
        <div class="box" (click)="openChatBot()"></div>

<ion-label>LEADERSHIP</ion-label>
```

I have to pass this text 'LEADERSHIP' from html to .ts on click event?
Please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you use variable, instead of static text? ex: inside controller `labelText = "LEADERSHIP"`, then `<ion-label>{{labelText}}</ion-label>`

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov i am not getting can you explain please?

Comment: Are you check my answer? if yes then response me...

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<ion-label id="label1">LEADERSHIP</ion-label>
```

ts:

```
var label = document.getElementById('label1').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

in `html` file

```
<ion-label [(ngModel)]="lable">LEADERSHIP</ion-label>
```

in `ts` file

```
public lable:any;
console.log("---------Label---------"+lable);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I am getting this ---------Label---------undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can create one variable into your .ts file and the use it into your .html.

.ts

```
export class YourTsFile {

    // Our translated text strings
   yourLabelVariable: string;

    constructor(
        public user: User,

        etc...

    ) {
       this.yourLabelVariable = "Text you want to show";
      }
    }
```

then on your .html file..

```
<ion-label>{{ yourLabelVariable }}</ion-label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in the TS file and assign the value to it.

In html put the same variable name between double {{ }}

Answer (score 0):

In **.ts** declare variable

```
labelVariable ="LEADERSHIP";

openChatBot(){
  console.log(this.labelVariable); 
}
```

In **.html**

```
<div class="box" (click)="openChatBot()"></div>

<ion-label>{{labelVariable }}</ion-label>
```